# Cannot parse SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I am using this code to parse a Date.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatterParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String s = formatter.format(formatterParse.parse(m.get("lastModifiedDate")));
```

m is a HashMap and someModifiedDate is coming as 2010-11-26

EDIT: I get InvalidTypeEception. java. Genereated value (java.sql.Date) incompatible with java.lang.String

Comment: Why r u formatting it 2 times?

Comment: @RMT: according to the code attempt, the map value is a `String` in `yyyy-MM-dd` format which he just want to convert to a `String` in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. @Kaushik: can you please be more specific about the problem? What happens instead?

Comment: I just tried it. it seems to work. whats the error?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me http://ideone.com/8zYrH

Comment: I think I read a few days ago about some JVMs not doing this right.  Are you using Java 6 or 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet below works fine.

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("lastModifiedDate", "2010-11-26");
}};

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatterParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String s = formatter.format(formatterParse.parse(m.get("lastModifiedDate")));

System.out.println(s);
```

The output is `11/26/2010`, thus either

1. ...you expected something different (*what?*) in which case you need to revise your code, or
2. ...something is wrong in your code elsewhere.